# How do I find the meaning of 'This' in following Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript, this

What does this.radioStation refer to in the following code: does 'this.radiostaion' refer to Car or the function chagestation. Your input/ clarification would be appreciated. Any good rule of thumb to clear this up?

```
var Car = function () {

    var gasolineLevel = 10;

    function useGas (amt) {
        if(gasolineLevel - amt < 0) {
            console.log("out of gas :[");
        } else {
            gasolineLevel -= amt;
        }
    };

    return {
        radioStation: "104.5",

        changeStation: function (station) {
            this.radioStation = station;

        },
        go: function (speed) { useGas(speed); }
    };
};


var Ferrari = Car();


console.log(Ferrari);

console.log(Ferrari.go(2));

console.log(Ferrari.go(10));
```

Comment: `this` is effectively a function parameter. It's set by every call.

Comment: have you tried reading up on the topic? It's generally considered that you should before asking here.

Comment: @melpomene: In normal functions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In `changeStation`, `this` will be whatever it was set to when calling `changeStation`. In normal functions, `this` is effectively a hidden argument that's determined by how the function is called.

In that specific example, you never call `changeStation`, so we can't tell you what `this` will be if/when you do.

*If* you called it like this:

```
var ferrari = Car();
ferrari.changeStation();
```

...then `this` would refer to the object created by `Car` (the one referenced by `ferrari`, created by the object initializer returned by `Car` at the end), because we called `changeStation` as part of a property accessor operation on `ferrari`.

But if you called it like this:

```
var ferrari = Car();
var changeStation = ferrari.changeStation;
changeStation();
```

then `this` would refer to the global object (in loose mode) or would be `undefined` (in strict mode).